# How to apply scales::percent or scales::percent_format() to prop.table in R to format numbers as percentages

Tags: r, formatting, plyr, percentage, crosstab

Consider the following example:

```
tab <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$cyl, dnn = c("vs", "cylinder"))
prop.table(tab)
#    cylinder
# vs        4       6       8
#   0 0.03125 0.09375 0.43750
#   1 0.31250 0.12500 0.00000

round(prop.table(tab)*100, 1)
#    cylinder
# vs     4    6    8
#   0  3.1  9.4 43.8
#   1 31.2 12.5  0.0
```

Desired output:

```
#    cylinder
# vs      4     6     8
#   0  3.1%  9.4% 43.8%
#   1 31.2% 12.5%  0.0%
```

`scales::percent(round(prop.table(tab)))` **does not** work because there is no applicable method for `plyr::round_any()` applied to an object of class `table`.

I know I'm missing a simple workaround. Or perhaps a simple wrapper or pull request to `plyr::round_any()` could fix this for everyone?

Comment: `d <- round(prop.table(tab)*100, 1)` and `paste(d,"%",sep="")` ?

Comment: @rmuc8 Nope. That will output a vector.

Comment: `x <- paste(d,"%",sep="")`
`matrix(x,nrow = 2,ncol = 3)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pt <- percent(c(round(prop.table(tab), 3)))
dim(pt) <- dim(tab)
dimnames(pt) <- dimnames(tab)
```

This should work. `c` being used here for its property of turning a table or matrix into a vector.

Alternative using `sprintf`:

```
pt <- sprintf("%0.1f%%", prop.table(tab) * 100)
dim(pt) <- dim(tab)
dimnames(pt) <- dimnames(tab)
```

If you want the table written without quotes, then you could use for example:

```
print(pt, quote = FALSE, right = TRUE)
```

Comment: Close, but there are quotes around the values.

Comment: That's just the way `print` outputs character vectors and matrices. As added above you can just use the `quote = FALSE` option if needed.

Comment: Final step, right-justify the output and align the decimals.

Answer (score 3):

```
prop <- round(prop.table(tab)*100, 1)
x <- paste(prop, "%", sep="")
print(matrix(x, nrow = 2, ncol = 3), quote = FALSE)

#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
# [1,] 3.1%  9.4%  43.8%
# [2,] 31.2% 12.5% 0%
```

Comment: How about right-justified output and aligned decimals?

Comment: just add `right= TRUE`. You could find that within a few minutes yourself